# How to programmatically update a manifest.json file version number

Tags: json, powershell

I have researched ways of updating a package.json version number via npm.  Is there a programmatic way to update a json file version number in general or a manifest.json file specifically?  Preferably using PowerShell?  Using PowerShell I am able to read and parse the json.  But I don't know how to increment of number in this format

```
"version": "0.0.6.2"
```

Comment: semver.ps1: https://gist.github.com/mckn/4136080

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For future visitors this PowerShell script is working for me

```
$manifest = Get-Content '.\src\manifest.json' -raw | ConvertFrom-Json
$oldManifestVersion = $manifest.version
$manifestVersionNoPeriods = $oldManifestVersion.Replace(".", "")
$manifestVersionInt = [convert]::ToInt32($manifestVersionNoPeriods, 10)
$newManifestVersionInt = $manifestVersionInt + 1
$newManifestVersionString = $newManifestVersionInt.ToString().PadLeft(4,"0")
$newManifestVersion = [regex]::Replace($newManifestVersionString, "(\d)(?=\d*\d)", '$1.')
$manifest.update | % { $manifest.version = $newManifestVersion }
$manifest | ConvertTo-Json  | set-content '.\src\manifest.json'
```